# How can I give example of key of a HashMap in Open API (Swagger)?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

```
{
    "a_property": [
        {
            "key": "foo"
            "property_1": "a string 1",
            "property_2": "a string 2"
        },
        {
            "key": "bar"
            "property_1": "a string 3",
            "property_2": "a string 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I have given a Json, I am trying to write a schema for it. If I am using additionalProperties then I am not able to mention example of keys in the schema.

Comment: There's no hashmap in Json/OpenAPI, so it depends on how you serialize your map. If you just serialize it to an object, the key would probably just be a field on the object's schema.

Comment: Using additionalProperties we have defined a HashMap <String, DailyPayment>. I have to give example of the Key which is string. You can refer the below link. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.